# When NSolve for X, Y, only output solution for X

Tags: equation-solving, output, save

I have an NSolve with two equations and two unknowns (X,Y). There is a unique solution.

NSolve currently gives me the solution pair (X,Y). But I only want to read out one of the variables (say X). How can I do this?

Basically I would like to 3d plot (Plot3D) two planes, one for X and one for Y for a range of parameter values.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please add the code that is generating these results. Without it, we have no way of diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Although it would be nice to have some working code as example of what you are actually trying to do, I think if sol = NSolve ... is your solution x/.sol resp. y/.sol should do the job for you. This could be plotted in 3D with no problems I am aware of by simply turning sol into a function of the parameters.

Comment: Thanks. So I have basically this. 

Manipulate[
  Manipulate[
   Manipulate[
    Manipulate[
     Manipulate[
      NSolve[{x == a/(a + (1 - a)*x)*k*(c + (1 - c)*y) && 
         y == k*(b/(b + (1 - b)*y) - (d*a + (1 - d)*x*
                a/(a + (1 - a)*x))) && 
         0 \[LessSlantEqual] x \[LessSlantEqual] 1 && 
         0 \[LessSlantEqual] y \[LessSlantEqual] 1}, {x, y}, 
       Reals], {a, 0, 1, 0.1}], {b, 0, 1, 0.1}], {c, 0, 1, 0.1}], {k, 
    0, 1, 0.1}], {d, 0, 1, 0.1}]


It returns X and Y and I would want to plot them as two planes in the (a,b) space

Comment: Please, go to the help centre and read about proper code formatting, how to navigate the site, etc

Answer (score 1):

A single [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) can have multiple controls.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{eqns, soln},
  eqns = {
    x == a/(a + (1 - a)*x)*k*(c + (1 - c)*y),
    y == k*(b/(b + (1 - b)*y) - (d a + (1 - d)*x a/(a + (1 - a)*x)))};
  soln = NSolve[{eqns,
       0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1} // Flatten,
     {x, y}, Reals][[1]];
  Column[{
    ContourPlot3D[eqns,
     {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
     AxesLabel ->
      (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"}),
     PlotLabel -> soln],
    StringForm["x = ``", NumberForm[x /. soln, 3]]}]],
 {{a, 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{k, 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{d, 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]